# Create a table based on view - the fastest method, use multi threading

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view that pulls around 1mil of records; and it takes around 15 minutes for temp table to be created.
Nevertheless, only 1 of my CPU cores shows load, the other 7cores are available. How can I use all cores for this process?

```
create table feed_03_tmp as SELECT *  FROM feed_03;
```

Comment: Are you CPU bound or IO bound? And did you optimize you configuration parameters for your workload?

Comment: Depending on the view and the query plan you can try to give _that_ client more RAM to work with: `set work_mem to '1GB'`.

Comment: Setting work_mem very high does help sometimes, but is *generally* not a good advice. It all depends on the view-definition: if a merge-join is possible, that should be preferred (IMHO), especially for large result-sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL backends are single threaded and there is one backend per client so a single client can only use a single core. However for such a simple query I am pretty sure you are IO bound. If you are IO-bound the one core doing the work will be below 100% load if it is constantly at 100% you are CPU bound.

You could use more then one core by opening multiple connections and let each copy a selection of rows but as I said it is probably not going to help. Note that each connection will be in it's own transaction.

To improve IO you may benefit from storing your temp tables on a seperate drive. To do this create a tablespace on a second drive and add a TABLESPACE clause to your create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE feed_03_tmp 
  TABLESPACE my_temp_tablespace
  AS SELECT *  FROM feed_03;
```

BTW: the postgresql developers are experimenting with introducing multithreading but it probably will take sometime for it to get widely used and make it into a release.